# Generate URL to confirm orders from customer (WooCommerce)

Tags: php, wordpress, url, woocommerce, webhooks

I am working with many websites that's sell products using COD payment method and i want to send URL link to each customer using (SMS or WhatsApp) to confirm his order, and after the customer click the link changing status of order to (Confirmed) automatically.

Message Example:

> Your order had been received
> Details >>>
> to confirm your order please click here:
> httpa:[www.example.com/zxbxbsjxhsjshsh/](http://www.example.com/zxbxbsjxhsjshsh/)

I want to ask if this possible in woocommerce? or anyone have an idea.

Answer (score -1):

```
$confirm_order_link = wp_nonce_url( add_query_arg( array( 'confirm_order' => $order->get_id() ) ), 'woocommerce-confirm-order' );
```